# Finding the limit as $x$ approaches zero for $\left(x+e^{2x}\right)^{\frac3x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Finding the limit as $x$ approaches zero  of

$$\left(x+e^{2x}\right)^{\frac3x}$$

I honestly don't know what to do here.

Don't know if we can use the l'Hopital rule but i doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compose Taylor series
$$y=\left(x+e^{2 x}\right)^{\frac 3x}\implies \log(y)=\frac 3x \log\left(x+e^{2 x}\right)$$
$$x+e^{2x}=1+3 x+2 x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\log\left(x+e^{2 x}\right)=3 x-\frac{5 x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\log(y)=9-\frac{15 x}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^9\left(1-\frac{15 x}{2} \right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: Pls the 1 disappeared because log 1 = 0 right? And why the big O? And kindly explain the last part of your work for me...like the answer should be e⁹ so how will the rest of the numbers disappeare?

Comment: @AshalleySamuel. This is correct ($\log(1+x)\sim x$). The other terms  go to $0$ since $x\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} (x+e^{2x})^{3/x}$$
$$\dfrac {\ln L}3=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac 1x \ln (x+e^{2x})$$
$$\dfrac {\ln L}3=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac 1x \ln e^{2x}(1+\dfrac x{e^{2x}})$$
$$\dfrac {\ln L}3=2+\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac 1x \ln \left( 1+\dfrac x{e^{2x}}\right)$$
$$\dfrac {\ln L}3=2+\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac 1 {e^{2x}}\dfrac {e^{2x}}x \ln\left( 1+\dfrac x{e^{2x}}\right)$$

Note that:
$$\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac  {\ln (1+y)}y=1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac 1 {e^{2x}}=1$$
So that:
$$\dfrac {\ln L}3=2+1 \times 1  \implies L=e^9$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(x+e^{2x})^{3/x}= \exp(\frac{3}{x} \ln (x+e^{2x})).$

Now use L'Hospital for $\frac{3}{x} \ln (x+e^{2x}$ with $x \to 0.$

Comment: Ok Lemme try it

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$\left(x+e^{2x}\right)^{\frac3x}=\left(e^{2x}\right)^{\frac3x}\left[\left(1+\frac x{e^{2x}}\right)^{\frac{e^{2x}}x}\right]^{\frac 3{e^{2x}}}$$

Comment: Ok i got this one. But how do i apply the limit through? Is the 3/x not going to render it undefined?

Comment: @AshalleySamuel We have that $\left(e^{2x}\right)^{\frac3x}=e^6$ and by $t=x/e^{2x} \to 0$ we have by standard limit $$\left(1+\frac x{e^{2x}}\right)^{\frac{e^{2x}}x}=(1+t)^{\frac1t} \to ?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} [x+e^{2x}]^{3/x}\lim_{x \to 0} [1+3x+2x^2+..]^{3/x}=\exp[\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3}{x}[1+3x+2x^2-1]]=e^9.$$

Edit for OP When $L=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)} \rightarrow 1^{\infty}.$
Then $$L=\exp[\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\ln (1+f(x)-1)=\exp[\lim_{x \to a} g(x)(f(x)-1)]$$
Also use $e^{2x}=1+2x+2x^2+...$

Comment: I'm not getting this well

Comment: @ Ashalley Samuel You may see my edit now.

Comment: Yea i get your explanation now. The answer is e⁹ i guess